# trocar cor da linha

Tags: php

Olá, Estou tentando alterar as cores das linhas de acordo com cada status, por exemplo, se o status for cancelado pintar de vermelho, se for autorizado pintar de verde. Tentei colocar um if, mas não esta funcionando e o pior é que não apresenta nenhum erro na tela. a pagina a qual quero alterar é essa... Alguém poderia verificar se tem erro de sintaxe?! Obrigada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde que você quer mudar a cor, coloca o HTML na pergunta e se usa bootstrap por exemplo

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow, cara tente sempre postar o máximo de informações possíveis como o código completo, aonde está o problema e se houver o log de erro. Estas informações são essenciais para poder ajuda-lo. Tente ser sempre o mais claro e objetivo possível nas perguntas. :)

Comment: O melhor é você colar o conteúdo, e não printar.

Answer (score 2):

Mas, seguindo sua ideologia, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    foreach($consulta as $valor){ 
    if($valor->status==1){
        $cor = "#FFCC00";
    } else {
        $cor = "#EDEDED";
    }
    ?>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $cor; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $valor->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->nome; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->status; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Desta maneira atribuimos $cor de acordo com o status, se for 1 (no caso inativo), colocamos laranja como bg, se for 0, colocamos então cinza.

Comment: Na minha opinião eu não faria ===, faria somente ==, e usaria ao inves de cancelado, o status 1, 2, 3.. acho que fica mais organizado, e criar no banco o enum para determinar isso